# define list from val in object

Tags: scala

I wrote this:

```
    def fields(): List[String] = List(Fields.ZONE, Fields.API, Fields.LOCATION, Fields.FACTORY)

  object Fields {
    val ZONE: String = "Zone"
    val API: String = "API"
    val LOCATION: String = "location"
    val FACTORY: String = "factory"
  }
```

I want to find an intelligent way to define List in def fields without typing manually all constants wrapped in the Fields object. 
Any suggestions, please.

Best regards

Comment: How is this object coded? It is from your project? O is it outside of your control? - My impression is that the object itself contains a lot of boilerplate, maybe it would be better to write a code generator that produces the object and the list.

Comment: I think your approach of creating the list is suitable in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```
case class FieldNames(
  ZONE: String = "Zone",
  API: String = "API",
  LOCATION: String = "location",
  FACTORY: String = "factory",
)
object Fields extends FieldNames

def fields(): List[String] = Fields.productIterator.map(_.toString).toList
```

This uses the fact that a `case class` implements `Product` which allows you to enumerate the fields in the class.

Note that it would be more usual to omit the `()` and make `fields` a `val`:

```
val fields: List[String] = Fields.productIterator.map(_.toString).toList
```

Comment: I think in this way you can only have maximum 22 field names.